# Can 'Switch User' in Windows 7 work with Active Directory?

Tags: windows-7, security, user-accounts, user-profiles, active-directory

In Windows 7 you can 'Switch User' to anyone who's been configured locally on the machine.

Can this be extended to allow someone to switch to a user defined in Active Directory (the same directory for everybody, if that makes a difference)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [Running Windows 7 in Groups and Domains](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1195-running-windows-7-in-groups-and-domains/) :

> Windows 7 supports fast user switching
>   in domain, homegroup, and workgroup
>   configurations. When a user is logged
>   on to a computer running Windows 7,
>   you can use fast user switching to
>   allow another user to log on without
>   requiring the current user to log off.
>
> To switch users, press Ctrl+Alt+Del,
>   and then click the Switch User button.
>   In a workgroup, the Log On screen is
>   displayed as at startup. In a domain,
>   a screen appears with the message
>   "Press Ctrl+Alt+Del To Log On," and
>   you must press Ctrl+Alt+Del again to
>   display the Log On screen.

Just remember to to type the machine name when changing to the local login from domain.

Answer (score 2):

If your Windows desktop is added to the domain, then **yes** you can switch to any user you have created in your existing domain defined in AD.

I have tested this out (and currently use this network) with Windows Server 2008 servers and Windows 7 desktops.

Comment: Fast User Switching gets disabled on XP, when on a domain - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_user_switching

Comment: alright then I remembered it wrong! :) thanks for confirming it @paradroid

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can and it's a new ability to Windows 7 as, IIRC, the Fast User Switching gets disabled when using domains in previous versions (I cannot remember about Vista, but I think at least the Welcome Screen got disabled).

However, I have been doing the same thing for years, even with XP, by using [**Direct User Switching Task**](http://www.waybeyonduk.com/DUST/), which makes switching between users as quick and easy as switching between application with ALT+TAB.